# Spring Boot \ Hibernate: Custom Field Validation Fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a field custom validator in my Spring Boot project.
I was relying on the following example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator and more sources, but maybe I do something wrong because I don't see the expected error in the output (is that what I am suppose to expect as a validation product?)

The code is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>

@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@Validated
public class WebController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebController.class);

    @Autowired private WebService webService;

    @TeamIdConstraint
    private Integer homeId;
    
    @TeamIdConstraint
    private Integer awayId;

    @GetMapping("/matchresultbyids")
    public MatchStats matchResult(@RequestParam Integer homeId, @RequestParam Integer awayId)
            throws MissingTeamException, InvalidTeamIdExcpetion {

        this.homeId = homeId;
        this.awayId = awayId;

        return webService.matchResult(this.homeId, this.awayId);
    }
}

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = TeamIdValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TeamIdConstraint {
    
    String message() default "Invalid team id!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class TeamIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TeamIdConstraint, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    TeamResource teamResource;

    @Override
    public void initialize(TeamIdConstraint teamId) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer teamId, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

        int numOfAvailableTeams = teamResource.retrieveAllTeams().size();

        return teamId < 0 || teamId >= numOfAvailableTeams;
    }

}
```

Also, I don't like the fact that I must create fields specifically for applying the constraint annotation.
Is there a better way? Maybe this is the source of the error??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to set also ElementType.PARAMETER, and so I could use the annotation directly on the parameter and remove the redundant fields.